# Why do OpenGL buffers (and objects in general) work?

Tags: opengl, buffer, gpu

Here is what I understand about how OpenGL buffers work: Sending data from the CPU to the GPU is slow, so we don't want to send, say, vertex data vertex by vertex. Instead, we send vertex data to the GPU all at once, and inform the GPU how to interpret what we send it. Buffers are involved in this process somehow (that's the point I do not understand).

So how to do this? We follow the OpenGL object creation model:

1. Generate a buffer ID

   ```
   GLuint VBO;
   glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
   ```
2. Bind the buffer ID to a target buffer in the current state/context

   ```
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
   ```
3. Modify or query data. For instance, `glBufferData()` called on the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` can be used to send the vertex data.
4. Set the target back to default

   ```
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
   ```
5. De-allocate resources (edit: after the buffer has served its purpose; for instance, after the end of the game loop)

   ```
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
   ```

So at one hand I have the abstract idea of a block of GPU memory, and on the other hand I have a procedure to access that block, and I do not understand how those two correlate.

Comment: "*We follow the OpenGL object creation model*" No, that's the OpenGL creation *and destruction* model. It's like allocating an object in C++, filling in its data, and then immediately *destroying it*. Thus in the end, you haven't actually done anything. Step 5 makes steps 1-4 into a no-op.

Comment: But overall, it's really not clear what it is you're trying to find out. It seems like you're asking "what is a [buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object)", but at the same time you seem fuzzy on what an [OpenGL object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object) is itself.

Comment: Thanks for the link; it looks like it should have my answer.

I am trying to contrast this to C pointers: We create a pointer, we allocate memory and point to it using this pointer, and when we are done, we free the memory.

Comment: Doesn't your buffer will stick around for multiple passes of the game loop, eg when a particle system is emitting particles over time for a laser or fire effect? Wouldn't we delete the buffer when the game resources are cleaned up eg suspend / quit ?